# AAPT error on Debian 8.3 Jessie 64-bit

Tags: android, linux, debian, aapt

On Debian 8.3 Jessie 64-bit, when trying to build an Android application, I get the following error:

> AAPT err(Facade for 699210498):
>   /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory
>
> Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed
>   out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute
>   at /opt/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully
>   (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable
>   SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds   at
>   com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
>     at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have tried to install the missing library, but it seems to already have been installed:

> $ sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 lib32stdc++6 lib32gcc1 lib32ncurses5
>   Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading
>   state information... Done lib32ncurses5 is already the newest version.
>   lib32gcc1 is already the newest version. lib32stdc++6 is already the
>   newest version. libc6-i386 is already the newest version. 0 upgraded,
>   0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

I have tried basically all the solutions that I could find online, but none of them helped.

Trying to install ia32-libs (sudo apt-get install ia32-libs) gives the following message:

> Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another
>   package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source However the
>   following packages replace it:   lib32ncurses5
>
> E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Does anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try method from last post from https://github.com/godotengine/godot/issues/2728 ?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it doesn't find the package.

$ sudo apt-get install lib32z1
Package lib32z1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'lib32z1' has no installation candidate

Comment: @Andrei https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/lib32z1/download - there you can download deb package with lib32z1 package and install it manually